Solving partial differential algebraic equation in Mathematica
I have been searching the documentation a lot and, while PDEs and DAEs are solved, a full multivariate PDAE system was not easy to find. I have found elliptic PDEs.
I have 4 variables, $y_1$ through $y_4$, all functions of $t$ and $x$, but $y_4$ is an algebraic variable. I am specifying 3 ICs and 5 BCs (2 BCs for $y_1$ and $y_2$ as they appear as second-order space derivatives), and no IC/BC for $y_4$ as it should be calculated from the 4th equation at $t=0$. Here is the system of equations:
$$ \begin{align}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial t} &= - \frac{\partial (y_1 y_3)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial^2 y_1}{\partial x^2} - y_4 y_2 \\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial t} &= - \frac{\partial (y_2 (1-y_3))}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial^2 y_2}{\partial x^2} + y_4 y_2 \\
\frac{\partial y_3}{\partial t} &= (- y_4 -  \frac{\partial y_3}{\partial x}) y_3 \\
y_4 &= y_3-y_2
\end{align}$$
with ICs/BCs basically kept equal for ease for now:
$$y_1(t,0)=y_1(0,x)=0.01$$
$$y_2(t,0)=y_2(0,x)=0.02$$
$$y_3(t,0)=y_3(0,x)=0.03$$
For $y_4$, I shouldn't have to specify it as it should automatically find it from:
$$y_4(0,x) = y_3(0,x)-y_2(0,x)=0.01$$
For the flux BCs for $y_1$ and $y_2$,
$$\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x} |_{x=1} = \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x} |_{x=1} = 0$$
I tried to implement it in Wolfram and got this error: NDSolveValue::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.
Here is the code
eqns = {D[y1[t, x], t] == -D[y1[t, x]*y3[t, x], x] + 
     D[y1[t, x], x, x] - y4[t, x]*y2[t, x], 
   D[y2[t, x], t] == -D[y2[t, x]*(1 - y3[t, x]), x] + 
     D[y2[t, x], x, x] + y4[t, x]*y2[t, x], 
   D[y3[t, x], t] == (-y4[t, x] - D[y3[t, x], x])*y3[t, x], 
   y4[t, x] == y3[t, x] - y2[t, x]};
bcs = {y1[t, 0] == y1[0, x] == 0.01, y2[t, 0] == y2[0, x] == 0.02, 
   y3[t, 0] == y3[0, x] == 0.03, Derivative[0, 1][y1][t, 1] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][y2][t, 1] == 0};


Try NeumannVale instead of derivative bcs:
eqns = {D[y1[t, x], t] == -D[y1[t, x]*y3[t, x], x] + 
    D[y1[t, x], x, x] - y4[t, x]*y2[t, x] + NeumannValue[0, x == 1], 
  D[y2[t, x], t] == -D[y2[t, x]*(1 - y3[t, x]), x] + 
    D[y2[t, x], x, x] + y4[t, x]*y2[t, x] + NeumannValue[0, x == 1], 
  D[y3[t, x], t] == (-y4[t, x] - D[y3[t, x], x]), 
  y4[t, x] == y3[t, x] y3[t, x] - y2[t, x]}  ; bcs = {y1[t, 0] == 
   y1[0, x] == 0.01, y2[t, 0] == y2[0, x] == 2/100, 
  y3[t, 0] == y3[0, x] == 3/100 };
sol4 = NDSolveValue [{eqns, bcs}, {y1, y2, y3, y4 }, {t, 0, Pi}, {x, 
   0, 1}]


Plot3D[Evaluate@Through[sol4[t, x]], {t, 0, Pi}, {x, 0, 1}]


The derivative boundary conditions at x==1 are fullfilled quite well
Plot[Evaluate@{Derivative[0, 1][Function[{t, x}, sol4[[1]][t, x]]][t,1], Derivative[0, 1][Function[{t, x}, sol4[[2]][t, x]]][t,1]}, {t, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All]



Thanks! I found this answer much better and worked more easily. I am unfortunately still having trouble with the real, more complex problem I had tried to dumb down to create this one but I think I will have to try that on my own for a few hours and then just open a new question if it doesn't work as swapping this question out is too late. I guess I should have done that from the start...

@ZackFair You're welcome. I'm curious about the new question...

Haha just posted it. I seriously considered again to just edit it but in the end just decided to open a new question. You can find it here if you want. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/306370/cannot-specify-boundary-conditions-properly-for-partial-differential-algebraic-e

The latest packages for PDE use DirchletCondition as a container for the boundary condtions of the unknowns and for Neumann boundary conditions replace the right side $eq==0$ by a source term, that mimics the reflection by  the mirror principle locally.
Try
    eqns = 
 Simplify@
 {-D[y1[t, x], t] - D[y1[t, x]*y3[t, x], x] + 
 D[y1[t, x], x, x] - y4[t, x]*y2[t, x] == 
    -NeumannValue[0, x >= 1], 
 -D[y2[t, x], t] -  D[y2[t, x]*(1 - y3[t, x]), x] + D[y2[t, x], x, x] + 
 y4[t, x]*y2[t, x] == 
    -NeumannValue[ 0, x >= 1], 
  D[y3[t, x], t] == (-y4[t, x] - D[y3[t, x], x])*y3[t, x], 
  y4[t, x] == y3[t, x] - y2[t, x]}]


   Needs["MaTeX`"]
   CopyToClipboard[MaTeX[TableForm[eqns]]] 


   bcs = DirichletCondition[
{y1[t, 0] == 0.01, y1[0, x] == 0.01,
 y2[t, 0] == 0.02, y2[0, x] == 0.02, y3[t, 0] == 0.03, 
 y3[0, x] == 0.03 }, True]

 sols[x_,t_]= NDSolveValue[{eqns, bcs}, 
   {y1[t, x], y2[t, x], y3[t, x], y4[t, x]}, 
   {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1} ]

It's a bit funny, despite warnings MMA vs 13 finds a solution for {t, 0, 1}, but not for other real values of $t_\max$.
